# Pass Arraylist from fragment to its own Activity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, arraylist

I have a fragments that builds a songs ArrayList, i want to pass that ArrayList to the framgment's activity . I know i can use interface, but not sure how i could do it

```
public class SongsListFragment extends Fragment
{

    public interface passArrayList {
            public void onArticleSelected(Uri articleUri);    
            // from android guide i don't know what to do
    }


}
```

Here is what i have so far, please let me know why im getting NullPointer

on MainActivity

```
    @Override
    public void onFragmentSetSongs(ArrayList<Song> songs){
        songsArrayList = songs;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSongListItemClick(int position) {
        musicService.setSong(position);
        Song playSong = songsArrayList.get(position);
        txtCurrentSongTitle.setText(playSong.getTitle());
        txtCurrentSongTitle.requestFocus();
        musicService.playSong(); 

        btnPlayPause.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_pause));

        if (playbackPaused) {
            playbackPaused = false;
        }

        //setDownloaded();

    }
```

on Fragment

```
OnFragmentInteractionListener  songsCallBack;
OnFragmentInteractionListener  songsItemClick;

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    public void onFragmentSetSongs(ArrayList<Song> s);
    public void onSongListItemClick(int position);

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        songsCallBack = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) getActivity();
        songsItemClick = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    songsCallBack = null;
    songsItemClick=  null;
}

listView = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.listViewSongs);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                songsItemClick.onSongListItemClick(position);
            }
        });
```

on the method where i finish building the songArrayList, i did

```
songsCallBack.onFragmentSetSongs(songArrayList);
```

Error When i Click on ListView

```
at com..activities.MainActivity.onSongListItemClick(MainActivity.java:107)
            at com..fragments.SongsListFragment$1.onItemClick(SongsListFragment.java:194)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:308)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1478)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3480)
```

Error Position

```
 musicService.setSong(position);       //Main Activity (MainActivity.java:107)

 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            songsItemClick.onSongListItemClick(position);  < --  here
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change name of your interface so that it begins from capital letter. Then in your activity add this line to declaration of your activity: `public class FragmentActivity extends Activity implements PassArrayList`, override interface method. And in fragment add following:

```
PassArrayList mCallback;


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mCallback = (PassArrayList) getActivity();
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallback = null;
}
```

And somewhere in your code, when you want to pass your list of songs back to the activity call the method `onArticleSelected()` on your `mCallback` object and pass to this method your arraylist. Then this arraylist will come as an argument to the method `onArticleSelected()` in your activity and you could make with it anything that you like. But don't forget to nullify link to mCallback in `onDetach()` hook method to prevent context leak

Comment: everything seems to be ok with callbacks. Did you check whether your service is not null?

Comment: oh that was the reason, i actually was not connecting to service. When i connected to Service on onCreate, its fixed now.

Comment: I have a follow up questions since you are good at this stuff, ok do now when my app starts and fragment loads it passes in the array list correctly.. Now when I click on navigation button to replace current fragment with another fragment... That fragment is exactly the same as first fragment but with different array list... How would I update the array list to activity

Comment: I made seconds fragment exactly as first.. But I get the classcast exceptions as I defined on onattach

Comment: If I did understand you correctly then in your second fragment you have to declare second callback, and use it in your second fragment instead of interface of first fragment. Also you have to add another implements declaration to your activity, and in your second fragment you have to cast getActivity to the second interface

Comment: if you can answer the question about arraylist not updating on fragment replace here please: stackoverflow.com/q/26966752/284869