# Passing arraylist from multiple fragments to activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer, event-listener

I have a follow up question from my previous questions.

My app starts and fragment loads, it passes in the arraylist correctly using interface and listener method .. Now when I click on navigation button to replace current fragment with another fragment... That fragment is exactly the same as first fragment but with different array list... How would I update the arraylist in activity?

I get a classcast exception.

Here are how both of my fragments are implemented

[Pass Arraylist from fragment to its own Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26964741/2848698)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of the ClassCastException, did you make sure to have your MainActivity(know its MainActivity from MainActivity.java:107) implement the OnFragmentInteractionListener? If you don't that could be why you're getting that ClassCastException, because you're trying to cast your an activity instance(getActivity) to a subclass of which it does not share any inheritance relationship with (OnFragmentInteractionListener)

Comment: Ok the problem was that i was only implementing interface of first fragment in Activity. I changed call back names and implemented second fragment and now thats fixed. But the problem is the arraylist on fragment replace doesn't update.